# Can't figure out how to correctly call an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some JQuery that does a ton of stuff with reordering and adding links to the nav, but the important part is that it's supposed to hide every nav link except for the first one (by looping through the nav) when the page loads. The way the loop works is that it hides every link that doesn't have the class attribute: `class="top"`. 
This is working fine, except for when `var page = ""`. As you can see from the code, I'm trying to select the nav link that links to "index.php" and add the `class="top"` attribute to it when `var page = ""`. I don't know if this is right, but something appears to be breaking my entire javascript document. I don't even know if it's selecting the right element or adding the class attribute, because when `var page = ""` none of the nav links are hidden.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

This is the HTML of my navigation bar:

```
<nav>
    <ul id='nav'>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="skillsets.php">Skillsets</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the JQuery I'm using:

```
var is_mobile = false,
    page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ul = $('nav > ul'),
        li = ul.children('li'),
        href = li.find('a[href*="'+page+'"]'),
        is404 = true;
    if($('#mobile').css('display')=='none') {
        is_mobile = true;       
    }
    if(is_mobile) {
        orderList();
        prepareList();
    }
    /************************************************************/
    /* Reorders the list relative to the page the user is on   */
    /**********************************************************/
    function orderList() {
        //remove the right border from the contact link
        $(li.find('a[href*="contact.php"]')).removeAttr('style');
        //move element to top
        ul.prepend(href.parent());
        //set top elements class to "top"
        $(href).attr( "class", "top" );
        if(page != ""){
            //loop through the nav elements
            li.children('a').each(function(){
                //if the name of the page the user is on matches one of the nav links execute the command
                if (page == $(this).attr('href')) {
                    is404 = false;
                }
            });
            if (is404) {
                //if the user is on a page not in the nav, add a 404 link at the top of the nav
                ul.prepend("<li><a href='404NotFound.php' class='top'>404</a></li>");
            }else if(page == ""){
                //set top links' class to "top"
                $(li.find('a[href*="index.php"]')).attr( "class", "top" );
            }else{
                $(href).attr( "class", "top" ); 
            }
        }
    };
    /*****************************************************************/
    /* Prepares the list to be dynamically expandable/collapsible   */
    /***************************************************************/
    function prepareList() {
        //loop through the nav elements and differentiate the first nav link and the remaining nav links
        li.children('a').each(function(){
            //check if the link has the class: "first"
            if ($(this).attr('class') == "top") {// attribute value matches variable value
                //make the first nav link function as the button to open and close the nav

            } else {// attribute doesn't exist, or its value doesn't match variable value
                //hide the remaining nav links with a slideUp animation
                $(this).slideUp("slow");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: if you create a jsfiddle you will be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown I can't really do that because what the `var page` is equal to depends the webpage that the user is on.

Comment: what other values `var page` can have.Will it have values of hrefs?

Comment: You can mock `page`, reduce to the bare essential and post a demo, I don't see why not...

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: @Zword Yes, so, if for example I'm on ndi.grn.cc/contact.php or even ndi.grn.cc/contact.php?mail=sent it will return: "contact.php" and brings the contact link to the top of the nav. The 404 handler that you may have noticed actually adds a 404 link to the top of the nav if the page the user is on a page that doesn't match any of the links in the nav.

Comment: @LarryK i will add a working fiddle in 30 minutes .Check for it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am not the best with regex I am getting string(*filename*) in my fiddle with the help of  `lastIndexOf() & substring()`:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzmwg/)

```
/*Getting File name*/
var is_mobile = false,
    path = document.location.pathname;
    var qpre = path.indexOf('?');
    if(qpre!=-1)
    {
        var page = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1,path.lastIndexOf('?'));
    }
    else{
        var page = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);    
    }
/*End*/

/*Hiding li s with a href's not matching var page(string)*/
$('#nav li').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('a').attr('href')!=page)
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    if(page=="")
    {
        $('#nav li:nth-child(1)').show();
    }
});
/*End*/
```

---

## Update

***I have written a script which does all the functions you require in less lines of code***

```
var is_mobile = false,
page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)||[""]/*[0]*/;

if(page=="")
{
    page="index.php";
}
var i=0;
$('#nav li a:not([href^="'+page+'"])').each(
function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
    i++;
}).promise()
.done( function() {
    if(i==$('#nav li a').length)
    {
        $('#nav').append('<li><a href="404.php">404</a></li>');
    }
});
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzmwg/5/)

Comment: Your solution is so different from my code that I can't even tell what part has been added for JSFiddle and what part is the solution.

Comment: I can see you worked very hard on this answer, so I marked it as correct. It would work, but I would prefer to avoid yet another loop.

Comment: @LarryK I always give my 100% when I answer a question

Comment: Okay, do you have any ideas as to why this isn't working then `alert("Page: \""+page+"\"")` so page is equal to a blank value. However, `else if(page == "" || page == null){
    //set top links' class to "top"
    $(li.find('a[href*="index.php"]')).addClass("top");
    alert(true);
   }` doesn't display the true alert.

Comment: Try alerting variable page and see if it is alerting the correct value.If not working then post a complete fiddle required for this question

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that `alert("Page: \""+page+"\"")` returns Page: "" so page is equal to a blank value.

Comment: Post a fiddle then.Just add your current code there

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/r8ERu/ I didn't add in the CSS that I have because I didn't think it was important.

Comment: @LarryK add css also .You are using classes for jQuery so i need to know the styles you are using

Comment: Okay, done. I had to specify between my default CSS document and my mobile CSS document.

Comment: @LarryK ok i will try to solve it but will take time because i actually will have to see each line carefully.I will replay today ,will i be able to solve it or not and if i solve it will post the working code

Comment: Erm, I accidentally fixed it... I moved some brackets around and have no idea why that worked. Should I post my fixed javascript on another JSFiddle so you can tell me exactly why what I did worked?

Comment: Ok post your fiddle @LarryK

Comment: Okay, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Rk8S3/ and just so you don't have to search around through the code as much, the brackets I moved around were in the orderList() function.

Comment: It was happening becoz you didnt close condition:   `if(page != "" && page !=null){ .... }`.It was closing after other if and else if statements

Comment: @LarryK check the code that i added in my answer.May help you

Answer (score 1):

String.prototype.match returns null when there is no match (like an empty string).
I think you need to use:

```
page = (document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)||[""])[0]; // no path/relative
```

or

```
page = (document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)||["/"])[0]; // root path
```

The || makes a missed match function default to the single element array with a fallback string.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is incomplete, though. Now, it hides all the links, which means `$(li.find('a[href*="index.php"]')).attr( "class", "top" );` isn't adding the class to the first link (probably because it doesn't properly select it. Could you help with that? If you solve that problem I promise I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Yeah sure let me actually read the thing haha, I usually just reply immediately when I see a possible TypeError - gimme a few

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles your code always returns `/` no matter what the url is

Comment: No, that would be &&. If the left hand of || is not exactly: null, undefined, NaN, 0, "", or false, the expression reduces to the left hand.

Comment: LarryK - would you mind going over the goal again? I think I'm missing what you're trying to do

Comment: Also - use the $.addClass/$.removeClass API instead of attr to manipulate classes, better form and it won't override your classes wholesale.
http://api.jquery.com/addclass/
http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: No problemo! If `var page = ""` I want to hide all of the nav links except for the first one. I would achieve this by setting the first links class to equal "top" as there is already a loop in my code that only hides the links without that class.
 
By the way, thanks for your `$.addClass()`/`$.removeClass()` suggestion but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Comment: //check if the link has the class: "first" Are you performing the wrong check? Also, use $(someElement).hasClass("className") to check classes, could also be the break. I'm tired and it's hard to debug this without a jsfiddle ;)

Comment: You could solve it all pretty simply by using addClass, getClass, hasClass as your class manipulators - just add a special class to the index page right at the beginning and re-show the index.php link right at the end

Comment: The problem with your solution is that I don't always want the "index.php" link to be the one that isn't hidden. If page isn't null, I may want it to hide the "index.php" link and keep a different one visible.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I voted up most of your comments, as well as your answer to boost your reputation points.